# Why /}/ is a valid regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

`/}/` is a valid regular expression in JS:

```
alert('}}}'.replace(/}/g, "!"))
```

However, [the ECMA standard](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.1) doesn't seem to allow that:

```
PatternCharacter ::SourceCharacter but not any of:
      ^ $ \ . * + ? ( ) [ ] { } |
```

Why does the above work? Is this feature universally supported? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Likely the parser does not mind the ] without the [ - probably the same with } and }

Comment: I've never seen it *not* work, but that doesn't mean much. I've found several (most?) regex libs allow unescaped *closing* delims.

Comment: @Dave: It even works with opening delims: `/{/`

Comment: It also allows `/{/` and `/{}/`. If the braces don't have numbers inside them, they're treated as literals. This is an extension to the regexp grammar, which is allowed by the ECMA standard.

Comment: @Bergi Depends on the implementation; I wasn't referring to just JS implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html :

> Most regular expression flavors treat the brace **{** as a literal
>   character, unless it is part of a repetition operator like **{1,3}**. So
>   you generally do not need to escape it with a backslash, though you
>   can do so if you want. An exception to this rule is the
>   **java.util.regex package: it requires all literal braces to be escaped**.

Seems that javascript is not an exception.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html - Jan Goyvaerts has it covered, as usual.

Comment: You need to actually cite the source though. As in, link to it within your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Small correction: These are `RegExp`es, which are different from pure Regular Expressions.

> Why does the above work?

Because the JS implementation you're using does not strictly conform to the ES5 standard, which states that it should raise a `SyntaxError`. As Bergi commented, this is described in [$15.10.4.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.4.1).

> Is this feature universally supported?

No.  It should never be considered universally supported if it's not in the standard.

> Is it documented anywhere?

Probably not, it's just an artifact of undefined behavior.  Look to the documentation of whatever JS engine you tested on.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between "regexpes" and "pure regular expressions"? Also, could you link to the standard? I was unaware that there even is one.

Comment: @Tomalak There's a link in the question.

Comment: It is specified, see [§15.10.4.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.4.1): "*If the characters of P do not have the syntactic form Pattern, then throw a SyntaxError exception*"

Comment: @Tomalak: I guess by regexpes he means instances created by `RegExp` and "pure regexes" are likely *regular expression literals*

Comment: @Tomalak Here's a description of the difference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages

Comment: @Bergi You're right - it *is* specified.  Updating the answer.

Comment: @Deestan I would be surprised if the NFA created via regex literal is different from the one created via `new RegExp()`. But it seems I misunderstood you in the first place. You were referring to specific ECMAScript syntax, I was referring to regular expressions as a concept (hence my question for a standard).